# Single domain, single sign on scheme for Django/Java servlet

Tags: django, jakarta-ee, single-sign-on, session-cookies

I am investigating single domain single login scheme for my web app. 
A django front end is used for user sign in. Once on the django app, the user can access resources stored on a java servlet.
I would like to pass the session cookie back to the Django app from the java servlet when the user access the resources, having the django app then let the java know the user is legit and actually has rights to the resource requested.

I was thinking of just using json between the django and java servlet (the java servlet is actually a wowza httpProvider)

Is this a reasonable scheme?